# 500 internal server error with Ajax and .htaccess

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, internal-server-error

i have problem with an ajax.
When i execute my ajax call the response of the page is "500 internal server error".
I suppose is a problem derivated from .htaccess.

This is my code:

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/php/function_ajax.php",
        data: "action=doSomething",
        success: function(result){  
                alerrt('Yep, it\'s work!');
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
            alert(error+' - '+status+' - '+request);
            return false;
        }
});
```

This is my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On



RewriteRule ^font - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^images - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^js - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^php - [L,NC]



# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

and then the rewrite condition for my htaccess.

If i remove the condition "RewriteRule ^php - [L,NC]" it will return "page-not-found".

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your last 2 `RewriteCond` lines have no following `RewriteRule`. What exactly do you want your rewrite rules to be doing?

Comment: I neeed this conditions to verify if folder or file exists or to access to them.

Comment: But `RewriteCond` alone are useless unless there is a `RewriteRule` following them.

Answer (score -1):

alerrt('Yep, it\'s work!');

two r's in alert might be your problem